# Fatal error: Call to protected method TCPDF::_dounderlinew() from context

Tags: tcpdf

I'm trying to used a method called _dounderlinew(). I'm studying the other method that was list down on the documentation of TCPDF, and it was says that this method's access is PROTECTED. This is the reason why I can't make it work just like the others. Hmm Can anyone explain me why I'm getting errors like this and how can I used this method? THANKS.

Codes I USeds

$pdf->_dounderlinew(x, y, '');

Answer (score 2):

_dounderlinew() is protected because it is used in the TCPDF class to output the actual PDF code, based on your input, so it is of no use to you. As the PHP manual says:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class
>   itself and by inherited and parent classes.

By using it I assume you wish to underline text (maybe inside a cell), for that you can use [the SetFont function](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#afd56e360c43553830d543323e81bc045) and set the style parameter to 'U':

```
 SetFont($family, $style='U', $size=null, $fontfile='', $subset='default', $out=true)
```

And the other parameters as you wish of course.